# Adding Items to Multilist Field using powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions

Can any please explain me how to add multiple items to the multilist field. For me only last item is getting selected.

```
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$allItems = Get-ChildItem -Path '/sitecore/content/ListManagerTask' -Recurse
foreach($multilistItem in $allItems) { $item[$templateField.Name] += $multilistItem.ID; } 
$item.Editing.EndEdit() | Out-Null`
```

I want to assign all items in `$allItems` to multilist.

[image: This is how i'm getting]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't added any `|` character to split the IDs of selected items. 
This works:

```
$item.Editing.BeginEdit() 

$allItems = Get-ChildItem -Path '/sitecore/content/ListManagerTask' -Recurse

foreach($multilistItem in $allItems) { 
    if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($item[$templateField.Name])) {
        $item[$templateField.Name] += "|";
    }
    $item[$templateField.Name] += $multilistItem.ID.ToString()
} 

$item.Editing.EndEdit() | Out-Null
```

Comment: There are some code snippets which include working with multilist here https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/code-snippets/

Comment: Thank you so much sir...Its working fine...

Comment: @kohilavani I'm glad it worked. If you find this answer useful, you should mark it as correct. Upvoting is also encouraged.

Comment: Wow -- I was just looking for the same thing today... I found it more efficient to build the string and then do the assignment once rather than continuously editing the item

Comment: Item is edited only once. It's the field value which is updated multiple times. But you're right. It could be more efficient to build the string first and then assign it to the field value.